# How to submit a route overlay on my map and then to see it on the map?

Tags: overlay, here-api

I'm creating my android application with the Here Map Android Premium SDK. I would like to add route overlays and to calculate routes on them.

I tried to submit the example overlay described on their [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/custom-routing-extension/topics/example-submit-overlay.html). So my command with cURL is:

```
curl -G http://cre.api.here.com/2/overlays/upload.json  --data-urlencode "map_name=OVERLAYEXAMPLE1"  --data-urlencode 'overlay_spec=[{ "op":"override", "shape":[[50.10765,8.68774],[50.10914,8.68771]], "layer":"LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCN", "data":{"VEHICLE_TYPES":"0"}  }, { "op":"create", "shape":[[50.10937,8.68422],[50.10807,8.68525],[50.10737,8.68387]], "data":{"NAMES":"ENGBNDemo Road"}  }, { "op":"override", "shape":[[50.10937,8.68422],[50.10807,8.68525],[50.10737,8.68387]], "layer":"TRUCK_RESTR_FCN", "data":{"VEHICLE_TYPES":"truck", "WEIGHT_RESTRICTION":"3300"}  }]'  --data-urlencode "storage=readonly"  --data-urlencode "app_id=PN********7w"  --data-urlencode "app_code=n4***********9Q"
```

The server responds something with:

```
"response_code": "201 Created"
```

I can see my map has been correctly uploaded by listing it with :

```
curl -G https://fleet.api.here.com/2/doc/maps.json ...
```

I expect to see new route on the map and to be able to calculate itinerary through it, but I can't see it on my map and the calculation don't use it.

On this [api-reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html) I can see an "overlays" option to the calculation query. Shall I list all my overlays in this parameter to use them ? Is there something equivalent for the map display ?

More, is it possible to use this new route with the offline router ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see the below api document.

*Search for custom geometries by attribute filter, or download complete layer.*

https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html#operation%2FsearchAllUsingGET

Here is a sample.

```
https://cre.api.here.com/2/search/all.json?map_name=OVERLAYMYMAP&geom=full&layer_id=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCn&acceptMissingLayers=true&app_id={{app_id}}&app_code={{app_code}}
```

I hope this help!

Comment: Thank you. So what I get with this url request are the geocoordinates of the overlay. Then I have to display myself the lines of the overlay on the map. That's not really cool. Anyway, how can I launch a navigation mode with the JSON that I get from the fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json request as it takes into account my overlay ? Thank you